# How to differentiate touch screen desktop and simple desktop in device channel of sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, master-page, device-channel

Background:
Working with SharePoint one additional device channel, i include Phone, Android and "**Tab**" in inclusion rule for mobiles and tablets, everything was working as expected.

Problem
When one user try to access from its "Dell all in one PC". 
**In IE:** it shows the mobile version instead of desktop version and when try to access using **Mozila**, it gives expected result that was default version of SharePoint master page.

Question:
Now how to differentiate that the request coming from "tablet" or "dell all in one PC". Because both are touch screen but "dell all in one PC" is a big screen and mostly used as desktop not tablet. and i need to show the desktop version of master page on "dell all in one PC" not tablet version

For information User String is below from Dell all in one PC:
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0) like Gecko
It has the word touch that force sharepoint to open tablet version from device channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UserAgent is not enough to detect devices.

You can detect with JavaScript (Client Side!) and than act on it

see:
http://hgoebl.github.io/mobile-detect.js/